# Sitecore TDS and Team City - Locking Error

Tags: sitecore, teamcity, sitecore8, tds

I have a Sitecore Project and am using TDS to deploy the project and Sitecore items. This works fine on my local machine, and in my Dev configuration on Team City, but my QA build fails with the error:

```
Deploy failed. Reason: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Locking Error 5 ---> HedgehogDevelopment.Padlock.PadlockException: Locking Error 5 [E:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cf62a29aa8ef565f\TDS.Core\TDS.Core.scproj]
at HedgehogDevelopment.Padlock.u.H(String ?) [E:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cf62a29aa8ef565f\TDS.Core\TDS.Core.scproj]
at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.Service.TdsService.Unlock(String key) [E:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cf62a29aa8ef565f\TDS.Core\TDS.Core.scproj]
--- End of inner exception stack trace --- [E:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cf62a29aa8ef565f\TDS.Core\TDS.Core.scproj]
at HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.Service.TdsService.Unlock(String key) [E:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\cf62a29aa8ef565f\TDS.Core\TDS.Core.scproj]
```

I cant seem to find anything about this error.

Answer (score 1):

In our case, this was because of a mismatch in a version for `HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.Service.dll`. Make sure the version of the dll is matching with the TDS version that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem on my local machine and re-installing the Sitecore Connector solved the issue.